# Sonata Admin : Forgotten Password

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, sonata-admin, sonata-user-bundle

I am using Sonata Admin with SonataUser/FosUser bundles.

I want to integrate the "reset password" functionality from FosUser into Sonata. Is there a quick way to :

- integrate the "forgot your password" link into the sonata login page ?
- integrate the functionality with the "admin/" url prefix and the sonata html/twig layout ?

Answer (score 1):

I have modified the admin login template to add the reset password link, you must extend the SonataUserBundle in order to use your custom template, follow the [documentation](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/user/2-2/doc/reference/installation.html#extending-the-bundle).

The custom template must have the same name and the same directory as in SonataUserBundle. Here is the template I used :

Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Resources\views\Admin\Security\login.html.twig

```
{% extends base_template %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="connection">
        <form action="{{ path("sonata_user_admin_security_check") }}" method="post">

            {% if error %}
                <div class="alert alert-error">{{ error|trans({}, 'SonataUserBundle') }}</div>
            {% endif %}

            <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token }}" />

            <div class="control-group">
                <label for="username">{{ 'security.login.username'|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}</label>

                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" class="big sonata-medium"/>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="control-group">
                <label for="password">{{ 'security.login.password'|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}</label>

                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" class="big sonata-medium" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="control-group">
                <label for="remember_me">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="remember_me" name="_remember_me" value="on" />
                    {{ 'security.login.remember_me'|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}
                </label>
            </div>

            <div class="control-group">
                <a href="{{ path('fos_user_resetting_request') }}">
                    {{ 'forgotten_password'|trans({}, 'SonataUserBundle') }}
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="form-actions">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="_submit" name="_submit" value="{{ 'security.login.submit'|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```